# Numeric format and display issue in datagridview's column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting

I have a datagridview which it has some columns with Int data type. I want to format these columns as numeric formatted with thousand separators. I know how to do that but I have a bad problems when I set the "**AutoSizeMode**" property on "**AllCells**".
After form loading just 4 or five digits is appeared with three dotes at the end?!
Like this : 150,000... instead of : 150,000,000.
But when I set the "**AutoSizeMode**" property on "**none**" and set a static width to column, there is no problem for showing full digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DisplayedCells` as `AutoSizeMode`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> The following code example forces a column to automatically resize its
>   width to fit its contents.

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[2];
column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
```

**Trick :** Scott Hanselman wrote a beauriful and simple article on [How to auto resize columns in winforms DataGrid](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoIAutomaticallySizeAutosizeColumnsInAWinFormsDataGrid.aspx)

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work! I still have same problem!

Answer (score 0):

set your DefaultCellStyle property like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#.###"
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't read carefully. Try setting FormatProvider property:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
dgv1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = nfi;
```

or

```
dgv1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
```

if possible, but I don't have any IDE anywhere near to check that.